# VBA:Compare two date formats in vba

Tags: vba

How do we compare two date strings in vba, like "01.02.2013 < 02/02/2013"?
Whatever the dates are this always showing true. And two date formats are correct in the example i menioned.

Below vba code throws error.

```
Sub aa()
Dim a As Variant, b As Variant, c As Variant
a = Format("1.2.2012", "DD\/MM\/YYYY")
b = Format("2.2.2012", "DD\/MM\/YYYY")
MsgBox (a)
End Sub
```

Comment: Those aren't dates, they are date strings.  Convert them to the Date datatype first, then compare them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your dates (strings) to a format `CDate()` accepts. 02/02/2013 works, I think 02.02.2013 doesn't. Use `Replace()` if needed.

Then you can cast your String data into the Date datatype with `CDate(myString)`. Dates can be compared with each other by the means of the usual operators, such as > < =.

Answer (score 1):

Clean up the strings to the correct format (see what CDATE accepts, and then use CDate(a) >= CDate(b) to compare.

Comment: apologies, Aeronth - hadn't seen your answer, mine is the same.